# Best practice of updating a value on blur using Reactive Forms on angular

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

What is the best practice to update a `<input/>` value using Angular reactive forms?

I have 2 formGroup.

first, formGroup has a `blur` event that will update the input tag on the second formGroup

```
<input
   class="form-control"
   id="bill_firstname"
   type="text"
   name="firstname"
   formControlName="firstname"
   autocomplete="off"
   placeholder="Corporate"
   (blur)="onBlurTest($event)"
 />
```

second formGroup:

```
<input
  class="form-control"
  id="doc-first-name"
  type="text"
  name="doctor"
  formControlName="docFirstName"  
  autocomplete="off"
  placeholder="First Name"
  [(value)]="test"
  />
```

and on my `.ts` file I set it up like this.

```
 test = '';

  onBlurTest(e) {
    this.test = e.target.value;
    this.companySignUpForm.value.user.docFirstName = e.target.value;

  }
```

is there a correct way to do it? or is this acceptable?

thank you.

Comment: There is no need to use `this.test = e.target.value;` you can directly set the value by `(this.companySignUpForm.controls["user"] as FormGroup).controls["docFirstName"].value = e.target.value`

Comment: or you can use `[(ngModel)] = "test"` in the second control "docFirstName" and set `this.test = e.target.value;` inside `onBlurTest(e) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the value of a formControl, you need to use the API of formControl.
One options:

```
onBlurTest(e) {    
   this.companySignUpForm.get('use.docFirstName').patchValue(e.target.value)
}
```